# quartz integration with spring,null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

i am trying to integrate quartz with spring, a file location is passed to the **JobCSVfile** class from a jsp page but it is not taking that location and showing null pointer exception. And i also want to shedule the timing from the jsp page i dont know how to dothat since i am using the trigurring details in the **applicationcontext.xml**
applicationcontext.xml

```
<bean id="jobCSVfile"
    class="com.vxl.appanalytix.dataload.quartz.JobCSVfile">

</bean>
<bean id="JobA" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
<property name="jobClass" value="com.vxl.appanalytix.dataload.quartz.JobCSVfile" />
<property name="jobDataAsMap">
    <map>
        <entry key="timeout" value="5" />
    </map>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="cronTriggerJobA"     class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
 <property name="jobDetail" ref="JobA" />
<property name="cronExpression" value="0/5 * * * * ?" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
<property name="jobDetails">
    <list>
        <ref bean="JobA" />
    </list>
</property>
<property name="triggers">
    <list>
        <ref bean="cronTriggerJobA" />

    </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

with out sheduling in the **applicationcontext.xml** can we do it in any other way?

Comment: yes you can, all what you need to do is create trigger, grab scheduler bean from context, and add your job to it

Comment: could u please help me with a peace of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can show you what i have done, i use java not jsp (i don't know jsp)

first i created my job interface:

```
public interface JobI {
    void execute(Object[] args);
}
```

i needed to have same executable method for each job

then create job and beanify it

```
public class SimpleJob implements JobI {
    @Override
    public void execute(Object[] args) {
        for (Object o : args) {
            // String[] array = o.toString().split("=");
            System.out.println(o.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

// context file

```
<bean id="simpleJob" class="uk.co.utel.tcds.system.schedule.jobs.SimpleJob" />
```

now just create class where you will be adding new jobs ie JobController

```
   public JobController{
    private final StdScheduler scheduler;

    public JobController(StdScheduler scheduler){
        this.scheduler=scheduler;
        }

    public void addJob(String cronExpr){
        CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger("name","group");
        trigger.setCronExpression(cronExpr));
        scheduler.scheduleJob(getJobDetails(), trigger);
        }

    public JobDetails getJobDetails(){
        final JobI jobBean = (JobI) applicationContext.getBean("SimpleJob");
        final MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean jobDetail = new MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean();
        jobDetail.setTargetObject(jobBean);
        jobDetail.setTargetMethod("execute");
        jobDetail.setName("name");
        jobDetail.setGroup("group");
        return (JobDetail) jobDetail.getObject();
        }
    }
```

// context file

```
  <bean id="jobController" class="JobController">
        <constructor-arg name="scheduler" ref="scheduler" />
    </bean>
```

all what you need is to add id to scheduler

```
<bean id="scheduler"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        .....
</bean>
```

now when you want to use it with jsp, all what you need is pass jobController bean to your script and call addJob method

and right, i almost forgot, in different version of quartz might be different way to create `JobDetail` and `Trigger` objects